# How can i fix the error i get when i resume my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When ever i try to resume the flutter app after it being minimized it crashes with the error log show below:

```
    E/Surface ( 9933): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
E/EGL_emulation( 9933): tid 9952: swapBuffers(286): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
F/libc    ( 9933): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x3c in tid 9952 (1.raster)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Android/vbox86p/vbox86p:7.0/NRD90M/391:userdebug/test-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 9933, tid: 9952, name: 1.raster  >>> com.example.expense_app <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x3c
    eax e9a1ae78  ebx f6190ca0  ecx ec411a10  edx e9a1ae00
    esi 00000000  edi 00000000
    xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 0000006b  xss 0000002b
    eip f6169ad9  ebp d8c54ea8  esp d8c54da0  flags 00010282
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0006ead9  /system/lib/libgui.so (_ZN7android7Surface11queueBufferEP19ANativeWindowBufferi+185)
    #01 pc 0006dc97  /system/lib/libgui.so (_ZN7android7Surface27hook_queueBuffer_DEPRECATEDEP13ANativeWindowP19ANativeWindowBuffer+55)
    #02 pc 0000844d  /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so (_ZN20egl_window_surface_t11swapBuffersEv+93)
    #03 pc 0000bf99  /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so (eglSwapBuffers+585)
    #04 pc 00010d39  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglSwapBuffersWithDamageKHR+553)
    #05 pc 000112f7  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglSwapBuffers+55)
    #06 pc 00001045  /data/app/com.example.expense_app-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x1168000)
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Please any ideas as to how i can tackle this.

Comment: is this a real device or emulator ? if it is a emulator can you delete and create a new emulator ?

Comment: its an emulator. Alright, let me try that

Comment: also if you are new to flutter maybe you can install Discord and join the server https://discord.com/invite/N7Yshp4 please check all other channels https://flutter.dev/community they might help you and guide you.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @PedroAGSantos... i got a new emulator and it fine now..

Comment: Yes i am new to flutter. i am watching a udemy course on it. thank you, i just joined.